# Doctrine merge error with uuid strategy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, merge, doctrine

Doctrine throws an **EntityNotFoundException** when i try to re-merge a detached entity that hasn't been persisted yet but merged once then detached.

1. First merge sets the ID
2. Second merge searches for the ID in the DB and throws an exception

I need to detach and merge back the entity because it's used in a multi-step (multi-actions) form for both creation and edition.

```
class Customer {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
     private $id;



$cu = new Entity\Customer;
$cu = $em->merge($cu);
$em->detach($cu);
// Doctrine try to find a customer that doesn't exists
$cu = $em->merge($cu);
```

Strategy IDENTITY works fine but i absolutely need to use UUID.

Comment: Did not test it, but I think you can generate UUID before insert to avoid this problem.